# Do shared hosting providers typically let users run make?

Tags: linux, shared-hosting

I had an ersatz build server running on my website, hosted by Network Solutions.  Recently, I lost permissions to run `make` via PHP, presumably because of some silent server move or configuration change.  I have had problems with NS in the past, so this gives me another excuse to switch hosts.  Before I do that, though, can I expect other hosts to give me the luxury of running system commands like `make`?

Comment: I apologize for the single-tag lameness.  There are a few others that might be applicable (like [tag:permissions]), but I don't have enough rep here.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask if specific hosts(that you're presumably considering) allowed this, rather than if arbitrary unknown ones *might*?

Answer (score 1):

Any decent/competent web host should allow you access to make as there are no reasons not to and it's a pretty commonly needed utility.

Letting users compile their own custom build of PHP or install apps in their home directory poses no additional security risks to a properly configured server, and without access to basic utilities like make, there's not much point to having SSH access.